# Sincronização automática Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Olá, irei criar esta pergunta pois já li vários documentos do Firebase e não consegui nada até agora. Antes de tudo sei que minha pergunta pode ter várias respostas extensas, mas se alguém puder me ajudar, já agradeço desde já.

- Estou criando um app de de vendas, porém preciso salvar estas vendas
  online.
- Para os produtos estou utilizando o PARSE. Ela faz a consulta online e retorna os produtos. Se não tiver internet mostra uma aviso dizendo que estou sem internet.
- Mas nas vendas eu gostaria de fazer diferente. O usuário poderia fazer a venda normalmente e quando ele conecta-se em uma rede essas vendas seriam enviadas automaticamente.

Hoje em dia eu sei que existe várias bibliotecas que fazem isto (O Realm é uma e o Firebase é outra) Lendo a documentação do Firebase sei que ele faz isto também. Mas não consegui entender muito bem como funciona. Hoje já utilizo o Firebase em meu projeto. Utilizo o "módulo" Analytics deles. O restante nunca mexi.

Então gostaria de saber se alguém pode me explicar melhor isto ? Ou se alguém já fez este tipo de sincronização e se puder ajudar, seria gratificante.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Vou tentar ser o mais breve possível, e vou responder com base no firebase, e também com a premissa de um banco de dados local.

Em poucas palavras, é perfeitamente possível fazer isso somente para as vendas no caso, mas geralmente isso é uma decisão estratégica da sua arquitetura.

1. Se utilizar o Realm (um dos muitos db para android), você tem que ter uma rotina de sincronização manual ou agendada das vendas. Se tiver internet tente mandar estas vendas direto para o servidor, se não tiver salve localmente e depois a rotina vai enviar.
2. Se utilizar o Firebase Database com o modo Offline ativado, você tira esta necessidade de um job agendado para enviar estes pedidos, pois o próprio Firebase vai se encarregar de fazer isso.

O que poderia fazer, como já utiliza o PARSE no aplicativo e não ter que migrar para o Firebase Database, é seguir a linha da primeira alternativa. Acho que vai ser um impacto menor no aplicativo. Mas como é somente as vendas e não tem lógica de banco de dados muito complexas, acho que o Realm é um pouco demais, pode usar um SQLite comum mesmo.